# combining do.call() and debug() prints all arguments contents

Tags: r, debugging, do.call

I am using R and trying to debug a function that I call with `do.call()` for convenience.

Combining `do.call()` and `browser()` is problematic. Basically, all the elements of the list of arguments passed to `do.call()` are ***printed***, which, if the list contains for example a very large data table, is not sustainable.

Here is a reprex. I create a simple `getsum()` function that sums elements of a vector. I create a `func()` function that calls `getsum()` for a list of vectors.

```
#getsum returns the sum of a vector's elements 
#func returns the vector of the sum of a list of vectors


func <- function(vec_list){
    browser()
    sums = lapply(FUN=getsum, X=vec_list)
    sum = unlist(sums)
    return(sum)
}

getsum <- function(vec){
    sum = sum(vec)
    return(sum)
}


args = list(vec_list=list(rnorm(5), rnorm(5)))

do.call(func, args)
```

That's the output I get :

```
Called from: (function(vec_list){
    browser()
    sums = lapply(FUN=getsum, X=vec_list)
    sum = unlist(sums)
    return(sum)
})(vec_list = list(c(-0.0801864335418185, 0.448324209935905, 
-2.86518616779484, -0.359284963520417, -0.620062639582574), c(1.74835180362954, 
-0.904288222154223, 0.746007117029027, 0.625889703799832, -0.908748727897187
)))
Browse[1]>
```

One might tell me "why are you using `do.call()`?". Indeed, if I simply call the function myself, the problem does not arise (see below). In this example I don't need to use `do.call()`, but sometimes it's extremely convenient.

```
#instead of do.call() use : 
func(vec_list=args$vec_list)
```

The output is then :

```
Called from: func(vec_list = args$vec_list)
Browse[1]>
```

EDIT :

I have tried the argument `browser(skipCalls=TRUE)` that solves the problem but defies the purpose of `browser()`. It makes R executing all the function's command at once. Other suggestions welcome.